# Should I have more than 1 database connection?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have started to make a webapp with asp.net mvc2. I am using the built in users database that is available by default. I want to add tags and more stuff that will need to be stored in the database.

At the moment under data connections, I have ASPNETDB.mdf which has it's tables and all its other information.

If I want to make a tags table, do I create a new data connection or should I add it to that database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have multiple databases but it would make it difficult to perform queries. A single database could have many tables and it is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 2):

Put your tags table in the same database.

Databases can handle hundreds of tables.  Each table can be associated to other tables via key relationships.

Here's a good place to learn about designing databases:
http://www.databaseanswers.org/tutorials.htm